# Insert 1 million records using Laravel DB Seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using faker to get dummy data and trying to add 1million records. Somehow I only can reach around 100000 rows only, Following is my code

```
$no_of_rows = 1000000;

for( $i=1; $i <= $no_of_rows; $i++ ){
        $user_data[] = [
            'status' => 'ACTIVE',
            'username' => $faker->userName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'password' => $password,
            'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
            'surname' => $faker->lastName,
            'mobilenumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            'confirmed' => (int)$faker->boolean(50),
            'gender' => $faker->boolean(50) ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE',
            'dob' => $faker->date(),
            'address_line_1' => $faker->address,
            'address_line_2' => '',
            'post_code' => $faker->postcode,
        ];


}

User::insert($user_data);
```

I'm getting following error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted
```

I already set `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`

Any useful thoughts or solutions?

Comment: Each iteration is adding to the array `$user_data` by the looks of things so the array must be humungous when it runs out of memory. Create an array on each iteration and nullify it at the end after inserting data

Comment: Use laravel Queues https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues instead of seeding million data with seed

Comment: @RamRaider thanks, tried that, then only 1000 records updating

Comment: Ok - I think I see why - it is because of the chunk of 1000

Comment: try use SplFixedArray

Comment: Elements in array: 1000000 SPL Array: [MEMORY USAGE] At start: 0.25[MB] // At end: 1961.5 [MB]

Elements in array: 1000000 Native Array: [MEMORY USAGE] At start: 0.25[MB] // At end: 2046 [MB]

Comment: nearly 2 GB right. I think its not a good solution either

Answer (score 10):

The core issue of this problem is that the [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) lib instance (usually used to generate data in Laravel) is memory heavy and it doesn't get properly cleared by the garbage collector while used in large loops.

I agree with the chucked processing that @[Rob Mkrtchyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6899900/rob-mkrtchyan) added above but since this is Laravel I would suggest a more elegant solution using the Factory facility.

You can create a specific model factory (in Laravel 5.3 this should be placed in database/factories/), for instance:

```
$factory->define(Tests::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'status' => 'ACTIVE',
        'username' => $faker->userName,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
        'surname' => $faker->lastName,
        'mobilenumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'confirmed' => (int)$faker->boolean(50),
        'gender' => $faker->boolean(50) ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE',
        'dob' => $faker->date(),
        'address_line_1' => $faker->address,
        'address_line_2' => '',
        'post_code' => $faker->postcode,
    ];
});
```

Then it's a simple matter of running the factory within your dB seeder class. Please note that the number 200 indicated the number of seed data entries to create.

```
factory(Tests::class, 200)
    ->create();
```

The reasons for using the seed factory is that it allows you much more flexibility in setting variables, etc. For documentation on this, you can consult the [Laravel docs on dB seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#writing-factories)

Now, since you are dealing with a large number of records it's trivial to implement a chunked solution which will aid the php garbage collecting. For instance:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    factory(Tests::class, 200)
        ->create();
}
```

I did a quick test and in this configuration, your script memory usage should be around 12 - 15mb (depending on other system factors of course) regardless of the data entries created.

Comment: So, what makes the Factory so much more efficient here? Is it because internally Laravel chunks these inserts?

Answer (score 5):

The variables set in the `foreach` loop never get used so if the only intention if the foreach loop was to add a million records you could do away with the foreach and use something like this? This way the array used to populate the db is redeclared on each iteration rather than having more and more entries added.

```
$no_of_rows = 1000000;

for( $i=0; $i < $no_of_rows; $i++ ){
    $user_data = array(
        'status' => 'ACTIVE',
        'username' => $faker->userName,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => $password,
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
        'surname' => $faker->lastName,
        'mobilenumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'confirmed' => (int)$faker->boolean(50),
        'gender' => $faker->boolean(50) ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE',
        'dob' => $faker->date(),
        'address_line_1' => $faker->address,
        'address_line_2' => '',
        'post_code' => $faker->postcode,
    );

    User::insert( $user_data );
    $user_data=null;
}
```

On the basis of your last comment I can see why the use of chunks - no way to know the syntax of the sql before posting answer so perhaps this might be more suitable?

```
$no_of_rows = 1000000;
$range=range( 1, $no_of_rows );
$chunksize=1000;

foreach( array_chunk( $range, $chunksize ) as $chunk ){
    $user_data = array();/* array is re-initialised each major iteration */
    foreach( $chunk as $i ){
        $user_data[] = array(
            'status' => 'ACTIVE',
            'username' => $faker->userName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'password' => $password,
            'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
            'surname' => $faker->lastName,
            'mobilenumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            'confirmed' => (int)$faker->boolean(50),
            'gender' => $faker->boolean(50) ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE',
            'dob' => $faker->date(),
            'address_line_1' => $faker->address,
            'address_line_2' => '',
            'post_code' => $faker->postcode
        );      
    }
    User::insert( $user_data );
}
```

Comment: updated the question but there is a mistake `$number_of_rows` versus `$no_of_rows` and you are still adding a new array to the stack on each iteration.

Comment: This is wont work, coz everytime its running `INSERT INTO table_name ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )`

Comment: Hey, I tried this, Records are not going above 50000 records,

Comment: I don't know why this should fail at 50,000 records or so ~ perhaps a script timeout issue? You could reduce the chunksize to say 100 so each iteration would produce a smaller array for the `User->insert` function?

Comment: @RamRaider I came to a similar solution, and am chunking into 20s for my model factory since using 100 seems to delay the start of adding the records significantly, but I'm also noticing that as it keeps incrementing that it is getting slower and slower.  50,000 records is about half way to where I need to be, but i can't get passed 2000 without waiting for hours.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hello: Here is very good and very Fast Insert data solution

```
$no_of_data = 1000000;
$test_data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $no_of_data; $i++){
  $test_data[$i]['number'] = "1234567890";
  $test_data[$i]['message'] = "Test Data";
  $test_data[$i]['status'] = "Delivered";
}
$chunk_data = array_chunk($test_data, 1000);
if (isset($chunk_data) && !empty($chunk_data)) {
  foreach ($chunk_data as $chunk_data_val) {
     DB::table('messages')->insert($chunk_data_val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to insert 16 million records. And I found the best and quick solution.

With Laravel 9 factories and collection chunking, 50.000 rows were inserted **~1 minutes**.

With a simple array and `array_chunk()` I got **~30 seconds** for 50.000 rows.

All 16.000.000 rows were inserted within 40 mins :)

```
use Faker\Generator;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
```

```
        $accounts = User::query()->pluck('id');
        $faker = Container::getInstance()->make(Generator::class);
        $ownProductId = $faker->regexify('[LD0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{9}');
        $data = [];

        for($i=0; $i< 320; $i++) {
            for($v=0; $v< 50000; $v++) {
                $data[] = [
                    'createdAt'       => (int)date('U'),
                    'productId'       => $ownProductId,
                    'title'           => $faker->sentence(3),
                    'imageUrl'        => '',
                    'User_id'         => $accounts->random(),
                    'productIds'      => implode(',', $this->generateFakeProductIds($ownProductId)),
                    'parentProductId' => $faker->regexify('[LD0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{9}'),
                    'status' => $faker->randomElement(StatusesEnum::cases()),
                    'searchType'      => $faker->randomElement(SearchTypesEnum::cases()),
                    'url'             => Str::random(50),
                    'marketplace'     => $faker->randomElement(array_keys(MarketplacesConfigService::CONFIGS)),
                ];

            }

            $chunks = array_chunk($data, 5000);
            foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
                TestModel::query()->insert($chunk);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello: Here is good solution

```
public function run(){
    for($j = 1; $j < 1000; $j++){
        for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++){
             $user_data[] = [
                 'status' => 'ACTIVE',
                 'username' => $faker->userName,
                 'email' => $faker->email,
                 'password' => $password,
                 'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
                 'surname' => $faker->lastName,
                 'mobilenumber' => $faker->phoneNumber,
                 'confirmed' => (int)$faker->boolean(50),
                 'gender' => $faker->boolean(50) ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE',
                 'dob' => $faker->date(),
                 'address_line_1' => $faker->address,
                 'address_line_2' => '',
                 'post_code' => $faker->postcode,
             ];
        }

        User::insert($user_data);
    }
}
```

This code uses only 1000 lenght arrays in memory... and you can run this without changing any default php settings...

Enjoy,..